# Displaying dice number in C

Tags: c

I want to display all dice numbers at first and than only number of first dice, but i think it use the value d1 in main(). How can  I do that without using globel variable?

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<time.h>

void display_dice_value(int d1, int d2, int d3, int d4, int d5, int d6)
{
    d1=1+rand()%6;
    d2=1+rand()%6;
    d3=1+rand()%6;
    d4=1+rand()%6;
    d5=1+rand()%6;
    d6=1+rand()%6;
    printf("%d %d %d %d %d %d",d1,d2,d3,d4,d5,d6);
}


int main()
{
    srand(time(NULL));
    int d1,d2,d3,d4,d5,d6;
    display_dice_value(d1,d2,d3,d4,d5,d6);
    printf("\n%d",d1);
}
```

Comment: This call: 'display_dice_value(d1,d2,d3,d4,d5,d6);' cannot possibly change the values of its arguments as they are all passed by value, leaving d1 uninitialized.  Pass by address.

Comment: It does *not* use the value of `d1` etc in `main`. It uses the arguments as local variables, which do not find their way back to main.

Comment: 'void display_dice_value(int *d1, int *d2, int *d3, int *d4, int *d5, int *d6)'

Comment: Alternatively, consider making the dice rolls an array, which you can fill.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To start, you would need to pass *pointers* to each `di` to the `display_dice_value` function:

```
void display_dice_value(int *d1, int *d2, int *d3, int *d4, int *d5, int *d6)
{
    *d1=1+rand()%6;
    *d2=1+rand()%6;
    ...
    printf("%d %d %d %d %d %d",*d1,*d2,*d3,*d4,*d5,*d6);
}


int main()
{
    ...
    int d1,d2,d3,d4,d5,d6;
    display_dice_value(&d1,&d2,&d3,&d4,&d5,&d6);
    ...
}
```

However...

When you find yourself creating a bunch of variables with the same name and a trailing ordinal number, that's a good hint that you really want to be using an *array*:

```
void display_dice_value( int *d, size_t numdice )
{
  for ( size_t i = 0; i < numdice; i++ )
    d[i] = 1 + rand() % 6;

  for ( size_t i = 0; i < numdice; i++ )
    printf( "%d ", d[i]);
  putchar( '\n' );
}

int main( void )
{
   int dice[6];
   ...
   display_dice_value( dice, sizeof dice / sizeof *dice );
   printf( "dice[0] = %d\n", dice[0] );
   ...
}
```

**ETA**

As a final note, your `display_dice_value` function doesn't just *display* values; it *generates* the values as well, which can be confusing.  It would be better to have a separate function to actually generate your dice values:

```
void generate_dice_values( int *d, size_t numdice )
{
  for ( size_t i = 0; i < numdice; i++ )
    d[i] = 1 = rand() % 6;
}

/**
 * For flexibility, write to any output stream
 */
void display_dice_values( FILE * stream, int *d, size_t numdice )
{
  char *sep = "";
  fputc( '[', stream );
  for ( size_t i = 0; i < numdice; i++ )
    fprintf( stream, "%s%d", sep, d[i] );
  fputc( ']', stream );
}

int main( void )
{
  int dice[6];
  generate_dice_values( dice, sizeof dice / sizeof *dice );
  printf( "6 dice rolls: " );
  display_dice_values( stdout, dice, sizeof dice / sizeof *dice );
  putchar( '\n' );
  printf( "d[0] = %d\n", d[0] );
  return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Like this. If the values are to find their way back to variables defined in `main`, the function arguments must be pointers, and `main` should pass their addresses.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>

void display_dice_value(int *d1, int *d2, int *d3, int *d4, int *d5, int *d6)
{
    *d1 = 1 + rand() % 6;
    *d2 = 1 + rand() % 6;
    *d3 = 1 + rand() % 6;
    *d4 = 1 + rand() % 6;
    *d5 = 1 + rand() % 6;
    *d6 = 1 + rand() % 6;
    printf("%d %d %d %d %d %d\n", *d1, *d2, *d3, *d4, *d5, *d6);
}

int main(void)
{
    int d1, d2, d3, d4, d5, d6;
    srand((unsigned)time(NULL));
    display_dice_value(&d1, &d2, &d3, &d4, &d5, &d6);
    printf("%d\n", d1);
    return 0;
}
```

Program output:

```
4 4 1 6 3 5
4
```

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest the same thing as @haccks but declaring the variables the variables as `int d1` instead of `int *d1` and then passing the pointer: `display_dice_value(&d1,&d2,&d3,&d4, &d5, &d6)`. I think the other way will give you segmentation fault.

I know this belong in a comment of the answer but I cannot comment yet, sorry.

Answer (score 0):

In C arguments to the function are passed by value. `d1` in function `display_dice_value` is a copy of `d1` in `main`. Updating `d1` in that function will not affect the `d1` in `main`.  You can use pointers instead.

```
void display_dice_value(int *d1, int *d2, int *d3, int *d4, int *d5, int *d6)
{
    *d1=1+rand()%6;
    *d2=1+rand()%6;
    *d3=1+rand()%6;
    *d4=1+rand()%6;
    *d5=1+rand()%6;
    *d6=1+rand()%6;
    printf("%d %d %d %d %d %d",*d1, *d2, *d3, *d4, *d5, *d6);
}

int main()
{
    srand(time(NULL));
    int d1, d2, d3, d4, d5, d6;
    display_dice_value(&d1, &d2, &d3, &d4, &d5, &d6);
    printf("\n%d", d1);
}
```

Comment: You sure about those declarations in `main`?  What do `d1` through `d6` point to?

Comment: @JohnBode; Oops! My bad.